# Typing for pushing a new item into an array

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a model class which manages an internal property `_record` which is a record from the database. The model class is a generic base class and each model type extends this base class.

I want to provide two convenience methods for modifying properties on the record: **setValue** for setting a discrete data structure and **pushValue** to push a discrete data structure onto an array.

```
/**
 * Allows setting individual properties on the record
 * 
 * @param key the property on the record you want to set
 * @param value the value of the property
 */
public setValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
  this._record[key] = value;
}

/**
 * Allows setting an individual property on a record where the property
 * must be an array and result of the operation is the addition 
 * of a new array element
 * 
 * @param key the property name on the model's record
 * @param value an element to add to the existing array
 */
public pushValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: keyof T[K]) {
  if (!this._record[key]) {
    this._record[key] = [ value ] as T[K];
  } else if (Array.isArray(this._record[key])) {
    this._record[key] = this._record[key].concat(value);
  }
}
```

The `setValue` works fine but I'm struggling with the appropriate typings for the `pushValue`. The errors are:
[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

> I'm using Typescript 2.4.0

Comment: Appropriate typing looks like   `pushValue<K extends subset of keyof T where values have array type>(key: K, value: T[K][0])`. There is no way to express that in current version of TypeScript. **BTW** `array.concat` takes an array, so you need to `.concat([value])`

Comment: Can i not get around the lack of "where values have array type" with my type checking of `Array.isArray()`?

Comment: At runtime - yes of course you can, I just don't see any way to express the type for `value` parameter in `pushValue` function declaration, short of declaring it as another, independent generic type paratemeter for `pushValue` and relying on runtime check.

Comment: are there any ways to turn off the error so compilation will complete? I know you can do this with `tslint` but not aware of this functionality in TS generated errors.

Comment: This will typecheck without any type casts inside: `public pushValue<V>(key: string, value: V) `, (but you still get errors if you turn on `--noImplicitAny`)

Comment: yeah i'm struggling to find a more generic way of defining this and I do have _noImplicitAny_ turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.isArray(this._record[key])` does not work as type guard, `this._record[key]` remains typed as `T[K]` after it, probably because of indexed property access (there is similar issue reported here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483 , resolution is "declined for performance reasons".)

The suggested workaround for that issue is to pass intermediate variable instead of `this._record[key]` to the type guard, and it indeed works. For a simple variable, its type gets inferred as `const v: T[K] & any[]`, with `any[]` part coming from `Array.isArray` type guard, so this code compiles with `--noImplicitAny`:

```
abstract class Model<T> {

    _record: T;

    public setValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
        this._record[key] = value;
    }


    public pushValue<K extends keyof T, V>(key: K, value: V) {
        const v = this._record[key];
        if (!v) {
            this._record[key] = [value] as any;
        } else if (Array.isArray(v)) {
            v.push(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This indeed works. You are a genius. Should this issue be raised as an issue with Typescript do you think?

Comment: Found similar issue in their github repo. I updated the answer.